# Error al conectar a la base de datos MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Intento conectarme a la base de datos Mysql en PhpMyAdmin desde php para llenar una lista desplegable pero no se llena.
Comparte codigo en php:

Conexion.php

```
<?
$conexion = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '1234');
mysql_select_db('sistema_sms', $conexion);
?>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sistema SMS</title>
<link href="../css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../js/myjava.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    ENVIAR SMS
</header>
<section>
<form id="enviar">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="idPersona" name="idPersona">
                <option value="">Seleccione un numero del directorio</option>
                <?
                    include('../php/conexion.php');
                    $directorio = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM directorio ORDER BY persona_nombre");
                    while($opt = mysql_fetch_array($directorio)){
                        echo '<option value="'.$opt['persona_id'].'">'.$opt['persona_nombre'].'</option>';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <br>
            <input type="text" maxlength="160" id="txtSMS" name"txtSMS" placeholder="Escribe aqui tu mensaje...">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Enviar"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="respuesta" style="padding-top:10px;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Checa la ruta relativa de `include('../php/conexion.php');`, ahí indicas que subes un nivel `../`, entras a `php/` y dentro esta `conexion.php`. En general veo bien tu demas código, a menos que sea la versión de tu PHP que no soporte el [`mysql_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-connect.php)

Comment: Estás usando las funciones MySQL que se corresponden con tu versión PHP? Hace tiempo que mysql_query está obsoleto. En su caso está mysqli_query, haciendo referencia al objeto de conexión.

Comment: Sé más descriptivo con tu problema, de lo contrario nadie te va ayudar:. Edita tu pregunta especificando el estado de tu conexión, los errores que te arroja...